# Asymptotic expansion in a polinomial

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

The problem is about Perturbation Theory

1. Find the first-order approximation for the roots of:
   $$P^\epsilon(x)=\epsilon^2x^6-\epsilon x^4-x^3+8=0 $$ Here
   you no longer know the exact solution by radicands. How can you
   validate your asymptotic approximation? Compare where you can by
   setting a value of $\epsilon$.

I tried with dominant balance with the diferents variable but the only way is viable propose is
$x=y/\delta(\epsilon)$ with $\delta(\epsilon)=\epsilon$, but i find only one root and graphically there are two reals roots for $\epsilon<<1$.

Someone can help me? :(

Comment: Doing dominant balance you have $2+6a,1+4a,3a$ and 0 as exponents. For negative $a$, either $1+4a=0$ or $2+6a=0$ will remove two of them. Choose the one of these which results in the smallest error in the neglected term(s).

Comment: I want only the real ones

Answer (score 1):

Regular perturbation case: $x \sim c_1$ i.e. bounded but not small, and you get a perturbation of the unperturbed root $2$.

Singular perturbation case: choose $x \sim c_1 \epsilon^a$ with $a<0$ so that the two terms with largest negative exponent cancel out. Thus the question is what is biggest for negative $a$: $2+6a,1+4a,3a$? It depends what $a$ is, but you can sweep through all the cases where a cancellation is possible:

$$2+6a=1+4a \Rightarrow a=-1/2 \text{ retaining } -1, \text{ neglecting } -3/2 \\
2+6a=3a \Rightarrow a=-2/3 \text{ retaining } -2, \text{ neglecting } -5/3 \\
1+4a=3a \Rightarrow a=-1 \text{ retaining } -3,\text { neglecting } -4.$$

Only the second one is consistent, i.e. the terms that you are cancelling are actually the dominant terms. So this determines the correct $a$. And indeed if you use software to find the root for $\epsilon=10^{-10}$ and $\epsilon=10^{-40}$, you find they differ by about a factor of $10^{20}=10^{2/3 (30)}$.

This surprised me a little bit because it indicates that $\epsilon x^4$ only changes the large root by a regular perturbation!